# jqGrid inline multiple search Select dropdown

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i'm working on a project where i need to have 3 select dropdopwns kind off like this
[search Select Dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcH14.png)

below is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var MgroupFilter = ":[All];Starter:Starter;Controller:Controller;Finisher:Finisher";
var NgroupFilter = ":[All];Beginner:Beginner;Expert:Expert;Intermediate:Intermediate"
var GgroupFilter = ":[All];Mover:Mover;Watcher:Watcher;Sleeper:Sleeper"


        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            url: 'getList.php',
            mtype: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            page: 1,
            colModel: [
                {   label :"ID",name: 'ID',key: true, width: 75},
                {   label: "mgroup",name: 'M Group',width: 120, stype: 'select',searchoptions: { value: mgroupFilter}},
                {   label: "ngroup",name: 'N Group',width: 120, stype: 'select',searchoptions: { value: NgroupFilter}},
                {   label: "ggroup",name: 'G Group',width: 120, stype: 'select',searchoptions: { value: GgroupFilter }},
            ],
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            width: 100,
            height: 500,
            rowNum: 10,
            rownumbers: true,
            rownumWidth: 40,
            pager: "#jqGridPager"
        });
        // activate the toolbar searching
        $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar',{multipleSearch:true});
        $('#jqGrid').jqGrid('navGrid',"#jqGridPager", {
            search: false, // show search button on the toolbar
            add: false,
            edit: false,
            del: false,
            refresh: true
        });

    });

</script>
```

now if i only have one select dropdown in the filter area, it will work, as soon as i add another one whatever i select will result in a blank list. is there something i am missing in this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out i was having a couple of extra double quotes in my return data. So my data needed to be like this

```
:[All];list1:list1;list2:list2;..........;listx:listx
```

but i was returning

```
**"**:[All];list1:list1;list2:list2;..........;listx:listx **"**
```